# Owl Carousel adding one extra empty item in slider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, owl-carousel

I am using Owl Carousel within wordpress. I have two custom post types (news & events) and I am showing the latest 3 (events & news) in Carousel. I have same query and html structure for both post types but it adds an extra empty item only in news Carousel.
**Wordpress Query**

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order'=>'DESC',
    'orderby'=>'ID',
    'suppress_filters' => false
  );
$my_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

**Note:** The query is same for both CPTs with "post_type=>events" in events.
**HTML STRUCTURE**

```
echo '<div class="media_banner banner_bg">
    <div class="media_banner_carousel owl-carousel">';

    if( ! empty( $my_posts ) ){
        foreach ( $my_posts as $key => $p ){
        
        $date = date('d F Y', strtotime($p->post_date));
            echo '<div class="banner_block banner_bg">
                <div class="inner_container">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2 class="banner_title">'. $p->post_title . '</h2>
                        <span class="text"> <span>'.implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $p->post_content), 0, 20)).'....</span> <a href="' . get_permalink( $p->ID ) . '">'.$read_more.'</a></span>
                        <span class="date">'.$date.'</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
    }
   echo' </div>
</div>';
```

Owl is applied to "media_banner_carousel" class for both in same way. Please help.

**UPDATE:** The issue is HTML markup. most of the posts contains html list at the start. I was extracting first 20 words of the most which means some "li" tags were opened but not there was no closing "li" and "ul" tags. Which was corrupting the structure. So can somebody suggest how to account for that. I want to show only two list items in my carousel.

Comment: Add condition like `if(!empty($p->post_title)){` inside foreach

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  For eg, have you checked what `$my_posts` actually looks like in both cases?

Comment: Maybe one of your posts contains html markup? you didn't escape it when you echo it. There might be extra  `<` or `>` chars there

Comment: Exactly the issue is html markup